# How do i write string to content stream just like Html.RenderPartial?

Tags: c#, razor

I have this method:

```
public static void RenderHere(this IPictureElement picture)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.WriteLine(picture.ToString());
}
```

but this just writes to the body tag,
but i would like it to write at the location of

```
@{ picture.RenderHere(); }
```

Just like the

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial(); }
```

I allready have a helper, but wanted to add this too, since many use `@{ Html.RenderPartial(); }` instead of `@Html.Partial()`,

Comment: You're defeating one of the main principles of MVC which is separation between View and Controller (HTTP). Your approach is strictly HTTP dependent and does not conform to the View-Engines way of MVC. Why not use a View Helper instead?

Comment: I already have a view helper, but this doesn't answer my question.
Why have the Html.RenderPartial then? I see many use the Html.RenderPartial, which writes the html to the content stream, and even is a bit faster, then @Html.Partial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an HTML helper:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString RenderPicture(this HtmlHelper helper, IPictureElement picture)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString(picture.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.RenderPicture(picture);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely add this one too. But still doesn't answer my question. Perhaps i need to re-phrase it.